# Matrix Multiplication in Maple

Tags: matrices, maple

I am just trying to do simple matrix multiplication and for some reason the method I am using will not work. I have tried other float values in some matrices and sometimes it works so I'm at a loss for the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Maple 16. Here's the code:

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
A := Matrix([[.2047935304, -.1283655391], [-.1283655391, .2047935304]]):
B := Matrix([[0], [1.2]]):
Multiply(A,B);
```

When I try to run it, it never seems to compute it. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I just can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is $B$ coming out as a column vector? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Yeah, it comes out as a column. I don't get any error messages. It just tries to compute it forever so I have to cancel. I'll let it run for a while and see if an error message eventually materializes.

Comment: I finally got it to calculate it, but it takes an absurd amount of time for something I could do by hand. I tired larger matrices and it seems to calculate quickly sometimes. It just seems arbitrary. I could easily write a program in maple to calculate this so I don't understand why it takes so long. Is there a better way to multiply matrices?

Comment: The standard manner I would use to multiply matrices is the dot operator; i.e. A.B; which should do the correct thing. I'm not sure why it would take so long to compute.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the dot operator as well, but it didn't seem any better. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This is a software question and not about mathematics and so is off-topic here. A more suitable site for Maple programming questions would be www.stackoverflow.com or www.mapleprimes.com . fwiw the code you posted should be always fast. This looks like something to contact support@maplesoft.com about. It'd also make more sense to mention your OS platform and product version.